# Delayed form submission using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to delay my form submission so that when valid information is entered an alert pops up to tell the user that their information has been recorded. The page should then wait for X seconds before submitting the form.

I have managed to get the alert pop-up working with one of my other forms but for some reason it is not working with this one.

I'll include my JQuery code below, any ideas?

Thanks

THIS IS THE CODE FOR THE FORM THAT WORKS:

```js
$('#addprebooked_form').submit(function(e) {

  if ($('#addprebooked_email').val() != $('#addprebooked_confirmemail').val())
  {
   $("<div class='alert alert-warning' style='position: fixed; bottom: 0;'>The emails you have enter do not appear to match! Please check you have entered the visitors details correctly and try again.</div>").appendTo('#prebook').fadeOut(3000);
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
   $("<div class='alert alert-success' style='position: fixed; bottom: 0;'>Success! This visitor has been booked in for the time and date specified.</div>").appendTo('#prebook').fadeOut(3000);
   var delay = 3000;
   setTimeout(function () { $(this).submit(); }, delay);
  }

 });
```

THIS IS THE CODE I AM HAVING PROBLEMS WITH:

```js
$('#addevent_form').submit(function(e) {

  if ($('#addevent_form').validate().checkForm() === false)
  {
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
   $("<div class='alert alert-success' style='position: fixed; bottom: 0;'><p>Success! This event has been scheduled for the time and date specified.</p></div>").appendTo('#createevent').fadeOut(3000);
   var delay = 3000;
   setTimeout(function () { $(this).submit(); }, delay);
  }

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that will work, because `this` inside the `setTimeout()` handler will not refer to the `form` element.

Also calling the jQuery's `submit()` method will enter a recursive loop because that will again call the submit event handler.

In your case, you need to prevent the form submit in the handler either way, then in the [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) complete handler, you need to call the [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) element's [submit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) method.

```
$('#addevent_form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('#addevent_form').validate().checkForm()) {
    var form = this;
    $("<div class='alert alert-success' style='position: fixed; bottom: 0;'><p>Success! This event has been scheduled for the time and date specified.</p></div>").appendTo('#createevent').fadeOut(3000, function() {
      form.submit();
    });
  }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5ru715f7/)

Note: I'm not sure how the first example is working

Comment: Hi, this makes sense however it doesn't work when I try it. The alert does not pop up and the page does nothing when pressing the form submit button.

Comment: Can you try to recreate the case in the fiddle and share the updated link

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle. It seems to work there but not from my browser. http://jsfiddle.net/5ru715f7/2/

Comment: @NathanJrT then there is something else wrong in the page, did you check the browser console? is there any error?

Comment: Yes, there is an uncaught TypeErrror $(...).validate is not a function

Comment: @NathanJrT that is the problem, you are not including the [validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) which is providing `.validate().checkForm()`

Comment: Add `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>` after including jQuery, also call `$('#addevent_form').validate();` before the submit handler is added as shown in the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5ru715f7/3/

Comment: Knew it was something simple. Thanks, that solved it :)